# Get a 404 page already when calling with trailing slash

Tags: redirection, uri

My SEO agency complains about the following:

Let's assume the URL http://example.com/foo leads to a non-existing page. Then Drupal correctly responds with a 404.

Now,

- if I call http://example.com/foo/ (with a trailing slash),
- Drupal first redirects to http://example.com/foo (without trailing slash)
- and only then responds with 404.

The SEO agency says that this way I loose "crawl equity".

The **desired behaviour** would be that

- I call http://example.com/foo/
- and immediately get a 404 page.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You probably have the "remove trailing slashes" option of the Global Redirect module switched on, or an .htaccess/vhost rule doing it, something like that. I would ask your SEO company to clarify why a 301 redirect, which is what Google recommend to do themselves, would loose you "crawl equity" (whatever the heck that is!), just to make sure it's really worth changing this

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a written rule htaссess 301 redirect. Possibly it is written in the code or via modules.